# Nginx conf for codeigniter result 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I have setup my nginx conf following this link for my codeigniter server block
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/
with some addition like this

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;
    autoindex on;

    root   /var/www/server;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        location = /index.php {
              fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
              fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/server$fastcgi_script_name;
              include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 444;
    }


    location ~* ^/(assets|files|robots\.txt) { }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny        all;
    }
}
```

But turns out still routed to error_404 default by CI. Anybody could enlighten me? Thanks

Comment: Have you set the `base_url`, `index_page`? Is there any log on the CI regarding the URI for 404?

Comment: I have set `base_url` with proper site url and `index_page` with empty value

Comment: sorry, for being neglected this questions. I finally figured it out, it's a wrong case filename. Damned i didnt check throughly from my partner's commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's resolved, no need for nginx conf. Merely from small mistakes with filename